# Cauchy sequences product metric

Tags: metric-spaces

I've been trying to prove that if $ x_n, y_n $ are Cauchy then so is $ (x_n, y_n) $ when X x Y has a metric that induces the product of the metric topologies on X and Y, and apparently I'm missing something quite obvious because, referring to

[Cartesian Product of Two Complete Metric Spaces is Complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8239/cartesian-product-of-two-complete-metric-spaces-is-complete)

it is apparently as simple as saying that since we have an N for which $ d_X (x_n, x_m) < \epsilon $ and an M for which $ d_Y(y_n, y_m) < \epsilon $ then choose the maximum of these, giving $ d_{X\times Y}((x_n,y_n), (x_m, y_m)) < \epsilon $

But I don't understand the logical step. What do we know about the metric of the product that makes this true?

Comment: There are many ways to define a metric on a cartesian product of metric spaces.

Comment: I am aware of this..

Comment: Is your question referring to a specific metric on the product space then?

Comment: Any metric that induces the product of the metric topologies on X and Y

Comment: $\max \{ d_X , d_Y \}$ induces the product topology on $X \times Y$.

Comment: What about every other metric that induces the product topology? Metric equivalence doesn't preserve completeness so why is this sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined in the link

$$d_{X\times Y}\left((x_n,y_n),(x_m,y_m)\right)=\max\left(d_X(x_n,x_m),d_Y(y_n,y_m)\right)$$

And so when we take the largest of $N$ and $M$ both $d_X(x_n,x_m)$ and $d_Y(y_n,y_m)$ are smaller than $\epsilon$ for all $n,m\geq \max(N,M)$. And so is their maximum i.e the product distance.

Comment: And if $ d_{X\times Y} $ is any other metric that induces the product topology?

Comment: Cauchy property is a metric property i.e depends on the metric, meaning that two metrics inducing the same topology may have different Cauchy sequences. I have to look back far in my memory to show you a counterexample

Comment: Yeah, I must have misread the question I was set. Thanks for your help